# AngularJS + Jasmine: spy an event callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have issues to spyOn a method bind to an event with scope.$on in a factory service, with Jasmine. The real method originally passed is called, instead of the spy.
I've made a plinkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2RPwrw?p=preview

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

This is because of the way you're binding the callback. Change

```
service.$on('hello', service.method);
```

to

```
service.$on('hello', function() {
  service.method();
});
```

When you say `spyOn(service, 'method')`, you're saying "replace the value that is referenced at `service.method` with a spy." However, your original `service.$on` code doesn't look up the value at service.method *when the event is triggered*--instead it looks it up *when the service is initialized*. Thus, changing the reference that `service.method` points to *later* has no effect.